# C++ list remove_if compile error

Tags: c++, list

The error message I'm getting for the code below is:

```
    error C2662: 'DamageNumbers::IsAlive' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const DamageNumbers' to 'DamageNumbers &'
1>          Conversion loses qualifiers
```

.

```
bool CheckDamageNumbersAlive(const DamageNumbers& e)
{
    return !e.IsAlive();
}
```

I want to remove objects from a list when IsAlive() returns false for the objects in that list.

Comment: is `IsAlive` declared const?

Comment: Why is `CheckDamageNumbersAlive(const DamageNumbers&)` a member function of `DamageNumbers` if it doesn't access any data of the instance it belongs to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method

```
bool DamageNumbers::IsAlive() {...}
```

should be const:

```
bool DamageNumbers::IsAlive() const {...}
```